# using ajax on php spawned buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Right, I have no idea what to search for in this context, I've tried my hardest to splice together other peoples working code but I just can't get it to work.

I've got an ajax function that sends a request to a php page to load data from a database and then spit it back out on the initial page via $(var).html. The code functions as intended and spawns correct html on the page with all the needed attributes and data, however when I try to use another ajax function to interact with buttons spawned in from the js using their id tag but it wont work at all. Do I need to reload the js file every time data gets spawned in? I'm at quite a mess right now so any help would be appreciated. I'll post all the relevant code in for people to browse. Apologies if it's all a bit messy, it's a work in progress.

This is my Index.php file, it's very basic as it only needs to hold the login form and the rest of the site functions handle the rest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main/login.js"></script>
  <script src="main/dashHandler.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Particles Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="particles-js">
    <div id="login">
      <form action="./" method="post">
        <div>
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="name" id="name">
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="word" id="word">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="loginbtn">
        <div class-"err" id="add_err"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="dash" id="dashboard">
        <div class="dash" id="dashboardContent">

        </div>
        <div id="output">


        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', function(){
      console.log('particles.json loaded...');
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP that spawns the data I'm after, I want to be able to interact with certain buttons that the PHP spawns in.

```
<?php

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/main/config.php";
    include($path);

$user = $_POST['uname'];

$sql = "SELECT siteID, sitePath, siteOwner, siteName, siteCreation FROM sites WHERE siteOwner LIKE '{$user}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$id = $row["siteID"];
$path = $row["sitePath"];
$owner = $row["siteOwner"];
$name = $row["siteName"];
$creation = $row["siteCreation"];

echo    
    '<ul>
        <li>'.$id.'</li>
        <li class="lidata">'.$name.'</li>
        <li>'.$creation.'</li>
        <li class="libtn">goto</li>
        <li class="libtn">clone</li>
        <li class="libtn" id="del" value="' . $path . '">Delete ' . $path . '</li>
    </ul>';

}}else{echo "something died";}
$conn->close();

?>
```

This is my Javascript file, it handles the login function as well as interacting with the spawned in button.

```
// JavaScript Document
var username, password, bigman;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
    $("#dashboard").css('display', 'none', 'important');
     $("#loginbtn").click(function(){   
          username=$("#name").val();
          password=$("#word").val();
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "main/loginHandle.php",
            data: "uname="+username+"&pword="+password,
           success: function(html){  
           //this html passthrough variable is awesome, using fnc(var) gives you whatever shit the called php echos back, insanely useful for seamless passthrough :D migecki mageck  
            if(html=='true')    {

                $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"main/dashLoad.php",data:"uname="+username,success:function(dashPass){

                    //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
                    $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
                    $("#dashboard").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                    $("#dashboard").html(dashPass);

                },
                       beforeSend:function()
                        {
                            $("#dashboard").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
                            //$("#dashboard").html("<img src='main/Assets/load.gif' /> Loading...");
                        }

                       });

            }
            else    {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
             $("#add_err").html("<img src='main/Assets/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
            }
           },
           beforeSend:function()
           {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("#add_err").html("<img src='main/Assets/load.gif' /> Loading...");
           }
          });
        return false;
    });


    $("#del").click(function(){

        bigman=$("#del").val();

        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='main/Assets/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");

        console.log(bigman);

    });



});
```

If any more information is needed feel free to ask, I might have explained this terribly but hopefully my code will help it make sense.

Comment: It sounds like you need a delegated event handler if you're attempting to place an event handler on dynamically created elements, but I can't see exactly where in your code you're doing that. You may have a separate issue of creating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, which will also cause problems. I'd suggest using `class` attributes for those.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To apply event handlers to dynamically created content, use the `.on()` feature of jQuery. See more: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thankyou for the welcome, it would seem your suggestion is exactly what I'm looking for so I'm gonna put some hours into studying it. Thankyou very much for your help.

Comment: Random: [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) only has up to 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, all HTML Elements must have a unique ID. So `"del"`, if used multiple times, would become ambiguous. I would remove the ID attribute from the button and make use of Class.

For example, if you PHP returns the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1001</li>
  <li class="lidata">John Smith</li>
  <li>01/01/2018</li>
  <li class="libtn goto">goto</li>
  <li class="libtn clone">clone</li>
  <li class="libtn del" data-path="/jsmith">Delete /jsmith</li>
</ul>
```

Your JavaScript would be something like:

```
$("li").on("click", ".del", function(e){
    var bigman = $(this).data("path");
    $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
    $("#add_err").html("<img src='main/Assets/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
    console.log(bigman);
});
```

Hope that leads you in the right direction.

FYI, as `.val()` may work, it's often best to use `data-` like attributes. These can be read via jQuery using `.data()`. So for the path detail, you can use `data-path=""` in the HTML and then read it using `.data("path")`. See more: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cpyfwyhc/

Comment: I'm not amazing at JS or HTML so could you just clarify for me as to whether or not that JavaScript you recommended would work with multiple instances of the same list, for example if I have 3 lists and I want to fetch data from a button contained in the 2nd list would the js fetch the appropriate data? My wording is terrible, I know, but I'm struggling to put thoughts into words at the moment. Thanks for your really useful response too, gives me a lot to work with! :D

Comment: Yes, `$(this)` refers back to the targeted jQuery object. `.on()` works well enough with `$(".del").on("click", function(e){});` to bind a click event handler. Within the callback function, `$(this)` will refer to the specific element that was clicked, `<li class="libtn del" data-path="/jsmith">Delete /jsmith</li>`. A similar method would be to use `$(e.target)` where `e` is the event object that was passed to the function as part of the click event, and `target` is the element that was clicked. In the function, you can use `console.log($(this)); console.log($(e.target));` to see the diff.

Comment: @JoshWatson this example might help: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/cpyfwyhc/

Comment: Alright, so I've implemented your suggestions and read through the supporting documentation, however it just isn't detecting the click event on the buttons. I can't help but wonder whether it's because the JS is loaded in before the php spawns in the text but I'd assume that the event listener would still be on the lookout for an element with the .del class in it.

Comment: @JoshWatson PHP is server side, so it generates the code before the HTML is sent to the browser. Hence the JS cannot execute before the PHP.